# SQL Query From Same Table using external Table value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have data in a SQL Server database in the same table that needs to be brought into multiple columns.

I have two tables, `tblIVContent`:

[image]

and `TBLIVTextData`:

[image]

In order for a record to show up in `TBLIVTextData`, when the data is created in our UI, it creates a Content_id on module_id equals 84.

I would need automatically find any record in `TBLIVContent` that has a module_id of 84 to show up in a query that queries against `tblIVTextData`

The columns I need is FirstName will always have a Field_id of 531, Lastname will be field_id of 543 and so on.

End states I would need the following output

```
 FirstName     |      LastName.    |       JobTitle    |
```

Record 1 would be as follows:

- FirstName equals Content_id of 263229 and field_id of 531
- LastName  equals Content_id of 263229 and field_id of 543
- JobTitle equals Content_id of 263229 and field_id of 544

I'm not even sure how to do this. I don't feel that joins are the right way to go? Can someone lead me down the right path?

I don't necessarily want the answer (trying to learn here) but what's the right way to begin this? Google returned a lot but I am not sure it is what I need.

Comment: Q: So what exactly are you asking?  Do you need a trigger on "Insert" (to add new data from your UI)?  Or you just want to query existing data (so you can display it in your UI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    content_id,
    max(case when d.field_id = 531 then field_value end) firstName,
    max(case when d.field_id = 543 then field_value end) lastName,
    max(case when d.field_id = 544 then field_value end) jobTitle
from TBLIVTextData d
inner join tblIVContent c on c.content_id = d.content_id
where c.module_id = 84
group by content_id
```

Comment: I think this starts me down the right path!  Thank you, Now I have to figure out how that works with multiple records under module_id 84 and then marry the contents of each content_id because max only shows 1 record.

Comment: When I try do do that with MAX it only returns one result, if I attempt to do it without max I get tons of results including all NULLS

Comment: @Nathan: you need `group_by` for this. See my updated answer.